# ui-select with big text crushing my table

Tags: css, angularjs, ui-select

In my `<table>` I have ui-select field, and when selected text is big `<td>` became too wide and that crush all my table. I try to add `max-width` to ui-select or ui-select-match but it's not work.

```
ui-select {
  max-width: 10%;
}

ui-select-match {
  max-width: 10%;
}
```

How can I fix this? ([Plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/lodWuf4HjzX2uymaO2Al?p=preview))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the final html output **ui-select** and **ui-select-match** will be generated as classes. so use the below code to get the desire output.

```
.ui-select {
  width: 100px;
}

.ui-select-match {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Here is the [Plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/lodWuf4HjzX2uymaO2Al?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

feed blow code to CSS style. This is working for me.

```
table { 
table-layout:fixed; width:400px;
```

}